# transition в Internet explorer11

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
 <style type="text/css"> 
 img{
 display:block;
 max-width:300px !important;
  transition:transform .4s;
  -ms-transition:transform .4s;
  -webkit-transition:.4s;
  -moz-transition:.4s;
 margin:50px auto;
 }
 .images:hover{
   transform:scale(1.5);
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
   -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
   -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
   -0-transform:scale(1.5);
   -khtml-transform:scale(1.5);
 }
 .grey{
 -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
 -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
 -o-filter: grayscale(1);
 filter: grayscale(1);   
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);   
 filter: grayscale(100%);  
 filter: url('url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'>
<feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");');  
 filter: gray; 
 }
 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="http://throwbacksoundtrack.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/wallpaper-1162140.jpg" alt="" class="images grey"/>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $('.images').hover(function(){
             $(this ).toggleClass( 'grey')
         }); 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот это не работает в IE 11 , точнее не работает transition - как это исправить ?

Comment: Странно, но у меня работает. IE также 11-й.

Comment: у меня нет - не знаю почему -